# vim powerline + tmux not expanding to fill entire status line

Tags: vim, macvim, tmux, vim-powerline

I have vim and tmux set up. I'm trying to get vim-powerline to look like the first picture. I can achieve this if I have one instance of vim, then using :vsplit to achieve the following effect.

[image: Vim splits with vim-powerline working fine]

On the other hand, if I were to use vertical splits using tmux, vim-powerline ends up looking like the following:

[image: Tmux splits with vim-powerline looking weird]

I've tried to delete segments, but vim-powerline still truncates prematurely and extends to the next line.

I'm using Mac OSX Lion on iTerm2. vim comes from brew.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The UTF-8 characters used by powerline may have something to do with it. Try disabling them.

Comment: romainl, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What about the size of the window? Do `$ echo $COLUMNS` and `$ echo $LINES` match with `:set coumns?` and `:set lines?`?

Comment: Well, the size would depend on the tmux-ed vim window right?

Comment: "would". But is it the same, here? Your statusline is overflowing so the code responsible for drawing it seems to be somehow confused about the available width. So, is the width the same in tmux and in Vim?

Comment: Oops, my bad. In tmux, the left and right splits read `99` and `98` respectively. Lines are both `53`. Setting the width to `98` has no effect.

Comment: What is the value of `$TERM` in your tmux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried reinstalling tmux/vim powerline and checking $COLUMNS and :set columns, but they just didn't look working. Try

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

For me, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just ran into this issue as well. To be on the safe side, set the configurations to UTF-8 in vim and tmux as well: `set encoding=utf-8` for vim and `set -g utf8 on` for tmux.